.net maui unfocus or detecting a click outside of custom view
since it is not possible for ContentView to trigger Unfocused event, is there a work around on detecting when a view is unfocused? (aka, when clicked outside of the view)

Did you try using Frame?It inherits from ContentView, and it can receive Unfocused event.

I tried it, does not work. I guess it is the same as any other view who has the Unfocused event but does not support it.
I believe that only a few components like Entry and Editor support unfocused

You can add a control to the ContentView that can trigger the unfocused event, and when I testing on a simulator, clicking the Tab key on the keyboard can trigger the unfocused event.

IThanks for the response, Im not only using it for windows so I dont press tab, and the content view does not need a control in it... im pretty sure the unfocused will only get called if you tap on the control and click outside of it, and not the content view it is attached to

You can refer to this case: Xamarin.Forms detect Custom ContentView click outside event.

Thank you for your response, I have already read through that case but I don't understand how this could help me.
Im sorry of probably not understanding it right, isn't it just manually checking if any other view on the screen is clicked?
Idealy what I want is a simple way to detect unfocusing of the view from the view prespective (like a standalone view). I hope that makes any sense, thank you for your patience

you can try setting the ContentView into StackLayout, set tap gesture both on ContentView and parenet layout .

im not so sure how will that help me.. if the stack layout is as the size of the content view, it will only detect clicking on the view itself, which I can already detect that with Clicked event

You can refer to the answer of Xamarin.Forms detect Custom ContentView click outside event, even though it is about Xamarin, it also applies to MAUI

Have you tried wrapping a ContentView into a StackLayout and setting click gestures on the ContentView？
